# PL/SQL:, How to pass variable into SELECT statent and return all rows of results

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using an oracle database. I am used to SQL server but not familiar with PL/SQL for the Oracle database. 
How do I Set a variable that returns all the rows that contain the value of that variable: I am lost, I tried to understand, but it is not making sense to me. This si a recent attempt I made to to this.

```
DECLARE date1 varchar(40);
Begin
Select '''07/31/2013_09%''' into :date1 from dual;
End;
/
print date1


Begin
Select * from TABLE1 where start_time LIKE date1;
End;
/
```

I should get all the rows returned from this.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you get started:

```
create table table1 (
  start_time varchar2(10),
  foo        number
);

insert into table1 values ('xyz', 1);
insert into table1 values ('wxy', 2);
insert into table1 values ('abc', 3);

create type table1_obj as object (
  start_time varchar2(10),
  foo        number
);
/

create type table1_tab as table of table1_obj;
/


declare
  v table1_tab;
begin

  select table1_obj(start_time, foo) bulk collect into v
   from table1 where start_time like '%x%';
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a parametrized cursor and pass that date as parameter to that cursor as below.

```
   CREATE or REPLACE procedure proc1(p_date date)
   as
        CURSOR C1 (date1 date)is
              SELECT * from TABLE1 where start_time LIKE date1;
  BEGIN
      FOR i in c1(p_dat)
      LOOP
        .......
      END LOOP;
      END;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the understanding of several basic building blocks:

- You need a PL/SQL data structure where you'll save the data set queried from database table: [PL/SQL Collections and Records](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/composites.htm). See especially *nested tables* and *record variables*.
- You query the database with [PL/SQL Static SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm). See especially *`SELECT INTO` statements*. In this case there is no need for dynamic SQL.
- But of course it is bit harder to get a set of rows out of the database than only one row. Here the keywords are: [SELECT INTO Statement with BULK COLLECT Clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#BABEIACI). Note that depending on your query and table size bulk collection will potentially exhaust your server's memory (by loading millions of rows).

Here is an example that should give you a kickstart:

```
create table so26 (
  day date,
  event varchar(10)
);

insert all
into so26 values(trunc(sysdate - 1), 'foo1')
into so26 values(trunc(sysdate - 1), 'foo2')
into so26 values(trunc(sysdate - 1), 'foo3')
into so26 values(trunc(sysdate    ), 'bar')
into so26 values(trunc(sysdate + 1), 'zoo')
select 1 from dual;

select * from so26;

declare
  type event_list_t is table of so26%rowtype;
  v_events event_list_t := event_list_t();

  function get_events(p_day in date default sysdate) return event_list_t as
    v_events event_list_t := event_list_t();
  begin
    select *
      bulk collect into v_events
      from so26
     where day = trunc(p_day);

    return v_events;  
  end;
begin
  v_events := get_events(sysdate + 1);

  if v_events.first is null then
    dbms_output.put_line('no events on that day');
    return;
  end if;

  for i in v_events.first .. v_events.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i || ': event = ' || v_events(i).event);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Example output when `get_events(sysdate - 1)`:

```
1: event = foo1
2: event = foo2
3: event = foo3
```